# How do I get selected radiobutton value in controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using mvc.I am unable to get radio button value in controller.

```
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelecetdOption, m.Name, new {});
```

Comment: You will get only true or false based on the hidden control rendered next to the radio button.

Comment: Is it inside a form? What _is_ posted? What _does_ happen when you do _what_?

Comment: Murali would you please explain how I am gonna get value.
Thanks for reply

Comment: CodeCaster,
It is inside the form but I need to check whether radio button is checked or not in the controller Thanks for reply

Comment: Then in your action method check `model.SelecetdOption`.

Comment: I checked it I am getting nothing.
Could you suggest other way to check in controller whether radio button is checked or not

Comment: You don't need other suggestions, you need to fix your issue. The code you show should do just what you want. Show the relevant parts of your view, your model and your controller's action method and explain what happens when you do what.

Comment: @foreach (var m in Model.ComparePlan.PlanList)
    {                
                <div id="@m.CssClass.ToLower()" class="price-table">
                    <header>
                        <h3>@m.Name @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Plan.OptionSelected, m.Name ,new {@class=@m.CssClass.ToLower(), Id = "productname"})</h3>
                    </header>
                    <section class="price-details">
                        <p>$<span id="productprice">@m.Price</span><span class="price-recur"> per month</span></p>
                    </section>
}

Comment: You need to show your Controller's POST action too.

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like this in your view:

```
<input type="radio" id="rbOption1" name="rbMyChoices" value="Option1" />
<input type="radio" id="rbOption2" name="rbMyChoices" value="Option2" />
```

and then in your controller...

```
public actionresult MyAction(string rbMyChoices){
    if(rbDents == "Option1")...
    if(rbDents == "Option2")...
}
```

If you add rbMyChoices to your controller parameters, it will contain the selected Value of the rbMyChoices rbgroup.